# How to trigger a StaggerMotion again for react-motion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to re-animate a `StaggeredMotion` for react-motion by passing new props and setting state again. I believe that the render method is called but the animation does not appear again. Here is my redacted render() method:

```
render() {
    let configs = [];
    Object.keys(this.state.ripples).forEach(key=> {
        configs.push({
            opacity: spring(1, [95, 20]),
            scale: spring(0),
            fill: this.props.style.fill,
            strokeWidth: this.props.style.strokeWidth,
            stroke: this.props.style.stroke,
            transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
        });
    });

    return (
        <StaggeredMotion defaultStyles={configs} styles={prevStyles => prevStyles.map((_, i) => {
        return i === 0 ? {
            opacity: spring(0, [95, 20]),
            scale: spring(1),
            fill: this.props.style.fill,
            strokeWidth: this.props.style.strokeWidth,
            stroke: this.props.style.stroke,
            transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
        } : prevStyles[i - 1]
        })}>
            {interpolatedStyles =>
                <g>
                    {Object.keys(interpolatedStyles).map(key=> {
                        const {...style} = interpolatedStyles[key];
                        return (
                            <circle key={key} {...this.props} style={{
                            transform: `scale(${style.scale})`, opacity: `${style.opacity}`,
                            ...style
                            }}/>
                        )
                    })}
                </g>
            }
        </StaggeredMotion>
    )
}
```

I have tried setting the state in `componentWillReceiveProps` and verified that new props are received to set `this.state.ripples` as a new array but the animation does not occur again, it only happens on the first render of the element.

Comment: I have faced the same problem. I have managed to solve it with some forcing. In the **componentWillReceiveProps** i have used a js **setTimeOut** function. then first i set the state for the array to zero and then set the state of the array to the desirable array. So the animation works fine. It is because the div element regenerates and animates on the creation. one more thing i like to use react **Motion** component rather than **StaggeredMotion**

Answer (score -1):

Question: *how* are you setting state?

The React docs says: `Treat this.state as if it were immutable.`

Every time you want to change state, and in your case re-animate, you need to use `setState()` as opposed to directly manipulating `this.state`.

It's unclear from the amount of code you posted what is all going on with your component, but if you are not using `setState()` then you'll want to change that.

Comment: Yes, using setState()